# Mybb, google analytics

Tags: html, google-analytics

he creado un foro usando MyBB y estoy registrando mi página en google analytics.

Me dice que pque un codigo de tipo `<script>` en mi index, el problema está en que MyBB no trae ningún archivo index.html, con lo cual no sé donde pegarlo para poder compropar que la web es mía.

Comment: http://themefreak.net/blog/how-to-install-google-analytics-with-mybb/

Comment: Gracias, cuando llegue a casa lo probaré a ver si funciona

Comment: @phpMyGuel Lo he intentado pero siguiendo ese tutorial llego al punto de que no existen los tags de <head> o <body> en las plantillas, si me meto en la plantilla del header solo me salen divs, ni head ni body ni nada...